# Is it worth it?

Tags: soft-question, advice

I am studying pure mathematics at university, as well as minoring in physics. I am soon to finish to BSc degree, and I am considering continuing on with studying pure mathematics. However, I do have a lot of other goals I wish to acheive that have very little to do with mathematics, and sometimes those seem more important. I want to get other people's opinions about whether committing yourself to mathematics is really a worthwhile pursuit, and do other areas of your life suffer, or at least receive less attention, if one's pursuits are dominated by mathematics. Thank you.

Comment: Nobody can answer this question because it depends on how important mathematics is to you.  Will other areas of your life receive less attention if you focus on math?  Yes.  Will other areas of your life receive less attention if you focus on anything?  Yes.

Comment: For one thing, unless you have a privileged Math background (like getting a head start on the more advanced stuff in high school, or even in undergrad ), it is not likely to be a cushy road. Outside of the Ivies or main , richer schools, the road will be harder, and rewards will likely not come soon. It is good to know this ahead of time.

Comment: I think it depends on what you consider worth.

Comment: If you read about the mathematicians from the past in books and that is what you aspire to, it is very, very unlikely you will attain that. Not saying that's your dream, though. Even among the bright newly minted PhDs, there aren't enough professorship jobs to go around (pigeon hole principle) so if your goal is to become a professor, it will be a long road. Not saying either of these are your goals or that they aren't worthy goals but you shouldn't discard these facts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should ask yourself whether you simply want to *learn* mathematics, or whether you want to do *research* in mathematics. Because if you simply want to learn, you can do that at any point in your life, even after you've had a career in something else, etc. But if you want to do research-level mathematics at a university, then you have a fairly rigid career path you have to follow.